# Pandas DataFrame with continuous index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Index' : ['1', '2', '5','7', '8', '9', '10'],
     'Vals' : [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 5]})
```

This gives me:

```
  Index  Vals
0     1   1.0
1     2   2.0
2     5   3.0
3     7   4.0
4     8   NaN
5     9   NaN
6    10   5.0
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
  Index      Vals
0     1  1.000000
1     2  2.000000
2     3  NaN
3     4  NaN
4     5  3.000000
5     6  NaN
6     7  4.000000
7     8  NaN
8     9  NaN
9    10  5.000000
```

I tried to achieve this by creating a new dataframe with a continuous index. Then I would like to assign the values which I already have but how? The only thing I have so far is this:

```
clean_data = pd.DataFrame({'Index' : range(1,11)})
```

Which gives me:

```
   Index
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for your example it will look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Index' : ['1', '2', '5','7', '8', '9', '10'],
     'Vals' : [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 5]})
df['Index'] = df['Index'].astype(int)
clean_data = pd.DataFrame({'Index' : range(1,11)})
result = clean_data.merge(df,on="Index",how='outer')
```

And the result is :

```
  Index Vals
0   1   1.0
1   2   2.0
2   3   NaN
3   4   NaN
4   5   3.0
5   6   NaN
6   7   4.0
7   8   NaN
8   9   NaN
9   10  5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very nice solution and I learned something new :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `Index` column in the index (after casting as integer), select the rows `1` through `10` (which will create the appropriate `NaN`s) and reset the index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Index' : ['1', '2', '5','7', '8', '9', '10'],
     'Vals' : [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 5]})
df['Index'] = df['Index'].astype(int)

df = df.set_index('Index').loc[range(1, 11)].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Index  Vals
0      1   1.0
1      2   2.0
2      3   NaN
3      4   NaN
4      5   3.0
5      6   NaN
6      7   4.0
7      8   NaN
8      9   NaN
9     10   5.0
```

Comment: Cool, this is even better and very concise! Thank you for sharing this and have a nice day!